# Retrieves Remote Certificate, displays Validity

Tags: c#, beginner

I'm a Windows sysadmin who is new to C# and "professional" coding.  My background is in VBScript ("get it done") and I've apparently built up a number of bad habits.  I'm hoping a review of the following code can help me do things the right way when tasks are still easy so that more difficult projects go smoother.

I needed a program to connect to a given site and return the number of days until the certificate expires.  It also needed to be able to query against different ports and different protocols (HTTPS, LDAPS, FTPS).  I also added a /Verbose switch to return more info when used stand-alone.

I'm interested in where I should be using functions (and what code should be removed from Main) and better ways to parse the command line args.  Also, any obvious security issues since I am allowing CMD line input.  I really appreciate any comments!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace CertificateVerification
{
    class CertificateVerification
   {
    // Method for displaying program usage
    public static void Usage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nDisplays certificate inforamtion about URI\r\n");
        Console.Write("{0} URI[:PORT] [/V]\r\n", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    }

    // Method for ignoring certificate errors
    public static bool TrustAllCertificates(
        object sender,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Set basic variables
        bool verbose = false;
        string uri = string.Empty;
        int port = 443;
        List<string> display = new List<string>();

        // 1 or 2 arguments required
        if (args.Length < 1 || args.Length > 2)
        {
            Usage();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        // If the first argument contains a switch, exit
        if (args[0].Substring(0, 1) == "/" || args[0].Substring(0, 1) == "-")
        {
            Usage();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        // Set uri as the first argument
        uri = args[0];

        // Parse arguments
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            // Choose to display VERBOSE or USAGE
            if (arg.Substring(0, 1) == "/" || arg.Substring(0, 1) == "-")
            {
                if (arg.Substring(1).ToUpper() == "V")
                {
                    verbose = true;
                }
                else if (arg.Substring(1) == "?")
                {
                    Usage();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Unknown Argument Value: \"{0}\"", arg.Substring(1).ToUpper()));
                    Usage();
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                }
            }

            // Set URI and PORT
            if (arg.IndexOf(":") > 0)
            {
                uri = arg.Split(':')[0];
                port = Int32.Parse(arg.Split(':')[1]);
            }
        }

        // Use data from Arguments to connect
        // Ignore certificate errors
        X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate();
        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(uri, port);
            NetworkStream tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpStream, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(TrustAllCertificates));
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(uri);
            certificate = sslStream.RemoteCertificate;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        // Format display based on results from above
        display.Add("URI: " + uri);
        display.Add("   Subject:" + new string(' ', 14 - "   Subject".Length) + certificate.Subject);
        display.Add("   Issuer:" + new string(' ', 14 - "   Issuer".Length) + certificate.Issuer);
        display.Add("   ValidFrom:" + new string(' ', 14 - "   ValidFrom".Length) + certificate.GetEffectiveDateString());
        display.Add("   ValidTo:" + new string(' ', 14 - "   ValidTo".Length) + certificate.GetExpirationDateString());
        display.Add("   Days Left:" + new string(' ', 14 - "   Days Left".Length) + (Convert.ToDateTime(certificate.GetExpirationDateString()) - DateTime.Now).Days);

        // Display the results
        if (verbose)
        {
            foreach (var item in display)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int dtm = (Convert.ToDateTime(certificate.GetExpirationDateString()) - DateTime.Now).Days;
            Console.Write(dtm.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

I should mention that the program above is just one building block in a larger task that does the actual alerting, which is of course written in VBScript and called from Task Scheduler :).  I like the idea of a simple program that can stand on its own, and more specific tasks (alert when a certificate is about to expire) are handled elsewhere, which is why I didn't try to write a single executable to handle everything.

Comment: This "bigger program" sounds just like a monitoring system, such as nagios, naemon, op5. They already have plugins for certificate validations too...

Comment: I don't mean to argue with you, because you do have a point.  However I don't believe your comment is helpful from a 'code review' stand point.  Yes, I'm reinventing a small part of a larger wheel, but in doing so I'm learning how to write code.  I posted here not to get help a specific problem, but to learn about the ways to 'do things the right way' when it comes to writing a program - and using the above program as a building block in that direction.

Comment: If you purportely reinvent you can always add the tag reinventing-the-wheel. My comment was a friendly nudge towards existing alternatives. I had put constructive critizism in an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> // Method for displaying program usage
> public static void Usage()
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("\r\nDisplays certificate inforamtion about URI\r\n");
>     Console.Write("{0} URI[:PORT] [/V]\r\n", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
> }
> ```

If you need a comment to explain what a specific method is doing, you have named the method bad. That being said you should rename the method to `DisplayProgramUsage()` which makes the comment superflous. In addition, this method doesn't need to be `public`.

Comments should be used to explain **why** something is done in the way it is done. Let the code talk for itself about **what** is done by using meaningful and descriptive names for classes, methods, properties and fields.

> ```
> // Method for ignoring certificate errors
> public static bool TrustAllCertificates(
>     object sender,
>     System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
>     System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
>     System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
> {
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Here we have a comment which is lying. The method isn't used to ignore errors but to trust all certificates. In addition, why is this method `public` ?

> ```
> // Set basic variables
> bool verbose = false;
> string uri = string.Empty;
> int port = 443;
> List<string> display = new List<string>();
> ```

You should declare variables as near to their usage as possible. In this case you declare the variables **before** any argument validation takes place. For invalid arguments which are validated later this would be superflous.

Always validate arguments before any declaration and processing.

You should extract the validation to a separate method to keep responsibilities separated.

Your validation logic doesn't proper validate edge cases. Assume a user passes a second argument with neither a `/` nor a `-` in front. Then it would be seen as a valid argument which it isn't.

The following is dangerous as well

> ```
> if (arg.IndexOf(":") > 0)
> {
>     uri = arg.Split(':')[0];
>     port = Int32.Parse(arg.Split(':')[1]);
> }
> ```

for a given first argument of e.g `www.google.de:test` it will throw a `FormatException` which isn't handled by your program.

**As a rule of thumb:** **Never ever trust data entered by the user !**

Instead of `Parse` you should use [`TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a bool flagging if the string could be parsed to an integer.

Implementing the mentioned points would lead to

```
private static void ValidateArguments(string[] args, Action displayProgramUsage)
{
    if (args.Length < 1 || args.Length > 2)
    {
        displayProgramUsage();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }

    if (StartsWithSwitch(args[0]))
    {
        displayProgramUsage();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }

    if (args.Length == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    string argument = args[1];
    if (StartsWithSwitch(argument))
    {
        argument = args[1].Substring(1).ToUpper();
        if (argument == "V" || argument == "?")
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Unknown Argument Value: \"{0}\"", argument));
    displayProgramUsage();
    Environment.Exit(1);

}  
private static bool StartsWithSwitch(string argument)
{
    return argument.StartsWith("/") || argument.StartsWith("-");
}
```

---

### uri, port and verbose

I would add a `private class ProcessingParameter` like so

```
private class ProcessingParameter
{
    public string Uri { get; private set; }
    public int Port { get; private set; }
    public bool Verbose { get; private set; }

    private ProcessingParameter()
    {
        Port = 443;
        Verbose = false;
    }

    public static ProcessingParameter FromArguments(string[] arguments, Action displayProgramUsage)
    {
        ProcessingParameter processingParameter = new ProcessingParameter();

        string[] parameters = arguments[0].Split(':');

        processingParameter.Uri = parameters[0];

        if (parameters.Length == 2)
        {
            int port = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(parameters[1], out port))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The value representing the port has an invalid format");
            }
            processingParameter.Port = port;
        }

        processingParameter.Verbose = arguments.Length == 2;

        return processingParameter;
    }
}
```

which creates an instance by the `FromArguments()` method.

---

> ```
> X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate();
> try
> {
>     TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(uri, port);
>     NetworkStream tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
>     SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpStream, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(TrustAllCertificates));
>     sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(uri);
>     certificate = sslStream.RemoteCertificate;
> }
> catch (Exception e)
> {
>     Console.Write(e.Message);
>     Environment.Exit(1);
> }
> ```

This seems ok but should be improved. If an object implements `IDisposable` like streams it should be enclosed inside a `using` statements which takes care of disposing the object.

Fixing this is simple

```
X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate();
try
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(uri, port);
    using(NetworkStream tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
    using(SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpStream, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(TrustAllCertificates)))
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(uri);
        certificate = sslStream.RemoteCertificate;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e.Message);
    Environment.Exit(1);
} 
finally
{
    if (tcpClient != null)
    {
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

but it should be extracted to a separate method as well.

---

The code below `// Format display based on results from above` has a few issues:

- it doesn't belong in `main` but in a separate method to make the responsibility clear.
- the `List<string>` is filled regardless if `verbose` is `true` or `false`
- there is some strange formatting going on e.g  `+ new string(' ', 14 - "   Subject".Length)`. The `string` class has a [`PadRight()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s(v=vs.110).aspx) which fills a given string to the passed `totalWidth` by padding with spaces.

---

Putting all together the code will look like so

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValidateArguments(args, DisplayProgramUsage);

        if (ShouldProgramUsageBeDisplayed(args))
        {
            DisplayProgramUsage();
        }

        ProcessingParameter processingParameter = null;
        try
        {
            processingParameter = ProcessingParameter.FromArguments(args, DisplayProgramUsage);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            DisplayProgramUsage();
        }

        X509Certificate certificate = FetchCertificate(processingParameter);

        int daysLeftUntilExpiration = (Convert.ToDateTime(certificate.GetExpirationDateString()) - DateTime.Now).Days;

        if (processingParameter.Verbose)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FormatVerboseOutput(processingParameter.Uri, certificate, daysLeftUntilExpiration));

        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Days left: " + daysLeftUntilExpiration);
        }
    }

    private static void ValidateArguments(string[] args, Action displayProgramUsage)
    {
        if (args.Length < 1 || args.Length > 2)
        {
            displayProgramUsage();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        if (StartsWithSwitch(args[0]))
        {
            displayProgramUsage();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        string argument = args[1];
        if (StartsWithSwitch(args[1]))
        {
            argument = args[1].Substring(1).ToUpper();
            if (argument == "V" || argument == "?")
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Unknown Argument Value: \"{0}\"", argument));
        displayProgramUsage();
        Environment.Exit(1);

    }

    private static bool StartsWithSwitch(string argument)
    {
        return argument.StartsWith("/") || argument.StartsWith("-");
    }

    private static bool ShouldProgramUsageBeDisplayed(string[] arguments)
    {
        if (arguments.Length == 1) { return false; }

        string argument = arguments[1];
        string delemiter = argument.Substring(0, 1);
        if (delemiter != "/" || delemiter != "-")
        {
            return false;
        }
        return argument.Substring(1) == "?";
    }

    private static X509Certificate FetchCertificate(ProcessingParameter processingParameter)
    {
        X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate();
        TcpClient tcpClient = null;
        try
        {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient(processingParameter.Uri, processingParameter.Port);
            using (var tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            using (var sslStream = new SslStream(tcpStream, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(TrustAllCertificates)))
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(processingParameter.Uri);
                return sslStream.RemoteCertificate;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tcpClient != null)
            {
                tcpClient.Close();
            }
        }

        // this exists only because the IDE complains about returning a value.
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
    private static bool TrustAllCertificates(
        object sender,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
         System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static void DisplayProgramUsage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nDisplays certificate inforamtion about URI\r\n");
        Console.Write("{0} URI[:PORT] [/V]\r\n", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    }

    private class ProcessingParameter
    {
        public string Uri { get; private set; }
        public int Port { get; private set; }
        public bool Verbose { get; private set; }

        private ProcessingParameter()
        {
            Port = 443;
            Verbose = false;
        }

        public static ProcessingParameter FromArguments(string[] arguments, Action displayProgramUsage)
        {
            ProcessingParameter processingParameter = new ProcessingParameter();

            string[] parameters = arguments[0].Split(':');

            processingParameter.Uri = parameters[0];

            if (parameters.Length == 2)
            {
                int port = 0;
                if (!int.TryParse(parameters[1], out port))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The value representing the port has an invalid format");
                }
                processingParameter.Port = port;
            }

            processingParameter.Verbose = arguments.Length == 2;

            return processingParameter;


        }
    }

    private static string FormatVerboseOutput(string uri, X509Certificate certificate, int daysLeftUntilExpiration)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("URI: " + uri)
            .AppendLine("   Subject:".PadRight(15) + certificate.Subject)
            .AppendLine("   Issuer:".PadRight(15) + certificate.Issuer)
            .AppendLine("   ValidFrom:".PadRight(15) + certificate.GetEffectiveDateString())
            .AppendLine("   ValidTo:".PadRight(15) + certificate.GetExpirationDateString())
            .AppendLine("   Days Left:".PadRight(15) + daysLeftUntilExpiration);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It's going to take quite a bit more time than I have right now to digest it all, but I plan to make good use of it...